# Generate an image/email attachment with a chart in C#

Tags: c#, charts

I have a background worker that runs 24/7 on a number of servers.  I'd like for that worker to generate a number of emails containing either PNG's or PDF's that represent a number of data points on a few chart series, that are plotted on a chart.

Any suggestions on the controls or methods to use, in order to accomplish this?
We currently own Telerik's suite of products, if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest mschart.  It is included with .Net 3.5 and 4.  Here is the link to download the sample VS solutions from Microsoft:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Saving to a png is as simple as something like

`chartObject.SaveAs("file.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);`

And chart objects can be saved in various formats to memory streams too.

And the charts really can look great if that's important!

Answer (score 0):

For a quick a dirty solution, why not generate CSV that can be easily imported to a spreadsheet that is ready to plot the data?

More generally I would suggest that your backend processes don't produce the images and only collect and send data somewhere else. You could use *rrdtool* or *graphite* to do the collecting and plotting. This would allow you to have charts for a machine, aggregated charts from all servers etc.

Comment: I'd like to create an HTML email that has images baked in and provides the chart of the data right in the email.

Comment: If you have multiple servers this would mean multiple emails, correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand the point of the question, but multiple servers all work in a distributed but load-balanced environment and would be sending a daily email to every one of our customers with a daily report.  Logic that distributed the emailing job to run across multiple servers already exists and works and has nothing to do with the chart control.

Comment: My point is that if every server sends an email then if would have stats only for itself.

Comment: All servers pull data from a centralized storage.  This is not a problem.

Comment: I though so after your comments, but it wasn't clear from the original question...